# Problem with ActionScript 3.0 button to URL and root movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Okay, so, here's what the problem is.  I'm creating a flash site with each page being it's own movieclip and Scene 1 being the menu and other things that stay on the site.

I've created a MovieClip called 'HowWorksScene'.  The movieclip has 2 buttons that link out to different URLs, however, I'm sure that when 1 of the button scripts work, the same script will work for the other...so here's the problem that I'm having with the Button
    `stop();`
    `VidDemo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, video);`
    `function video(event:MouseEvent):void {`
    `var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest('www.youtube.com');`
    `navigateToURL(link); }`

Problem is that I cannot GET to that frame to even determine an error. The problem preventing me from getting to this point is a call function.

In the "HomePage" movieclip, when the button is pressed to go to the next scene, "Homepage" fades out and flys left then the next frame is 1 frame but activates the next movieclipe "HowWorksScene"...but without errors, it simply goes to frame 17 of "Homepage".  I've tried doing 
`_root.gotoAndPlay(17);`
but get an undefined error.  So, I guess my question is:
What is the BEST way to direct from within a movieclip to a frame in the parent Scene?  I've even tried using 
`gotoAndPlay(17, "Scene 1");`
And that still did not work.  Please let me know ASAP!

Comment: You are no longer in AS2, there is no _root, you just pass the root class as a paramenter to that button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(17, "Scene 1");
```